# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 1 Error

Tags: java

I am trying to do a factorial trailing zero exercise, but I keep getting array index out of bound error. Need help fixing this. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Exercise3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] list = new int [n];
    int num = 1;
    int div = 5;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        list[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
        while (list[i] > div) {
            count += list[i] / div;
            div=div*5;
            num++;
        }System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is raining the exception and what input is causing the error?

Comment: Try printing out the value of `n` and see what it says.

Comment: The array list has n elements, but there's no guarantee that while loop doesn't increment num, which will permit the i-loop to exceed n. - It might be advisable to specify what the program should do.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
```

and then

```
num++;
```

that increments at every circle.
Thats why.